# Can the dryer's heating element be saved?

Tags: repair, dryer

I just read why you shouldn't mend a dryer's heating element or coil.
What if the break just happens to be be two or three inches at the very end, or even just 1 inch from the end; can you stretch it out and complete the circuit?

It's for a Whirlpool Dryer.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter *where* the break is. You cannot repair the element without shortening it, which will reduce its resistance, causing it to burn hotter than it is designed to do. If you are very lucky it will just burn out again right away before setting your clothes on fire.

Of course the appliance designer allowed some safety margin in the specs, because manufacturing tolerances vary, and parts can fail after installation. So you would think you could get away with a little fudging of the heater element length. But what you cannot know is how close your dryer was to immolating itself before you started messing with it.

Answer (score 2):

Increasing the resistance makes it safer not less safer. Heater elements have Nickel - Chromium wires or Nichrome. The outer surface oxidizes and the resistance through the outside is higher. Obtain some nichrome wire. It you have access to the break, overlap the broken heater wires about 3/4 inch. Twist nichrome wire across the overlapped heater wires. Make sure the heater coils and added nichrome wire do not touch anything else. (The housing or another coil). The heater has a protective thermostat if it gets too hot. I have a new heater that I can install in my dryer. But my dryer has been working fine with this repair through multiple loads of clothes.

Comment: This will work a treat if done properly. - The reason electricians advise against the repair of heater elements is that the homeowner is always tempted to just join the broken ends together. Your method is really suitable only for the advanced handyman with some experience in repairing junked appliances. For the average DIY homeowner, the fuss and bother of obtaining proper nichrome wire and calculating the correct length exceeds that of locating a replacement element. +1 anyway

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could add a power resistor to replace the resistance you cut out.  You'd  have to size it properly.

Although, heating elements are not inherently complex or expensive.  A replacement element may be affordable.